# Unique NAME to clone() elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

How do I give an unique NAME or other ATTR to a element that is cloned?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain yourself a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hack-ish way to do this would be to use a global counter and keep incrementing it by One before adding the value to the name of the cloned element.

ex.

```
var count =1;
func some_func() {
     var cloneElement = $(form).clone();
     cloneElement.attr('name', cloneElement.attr('name') + count++);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.random:

```
$('.some_element').each(function() {
    var id = (Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000000000));
    $(this).clone().attr('id', id);
});
```

Or, if you'd like a "handle" on the original element, you could create a new id in this format:

```
ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_ID + SEPARATOR + RANDOM_NUMBER
```

E.g.,

```
$('.some_element').each(function() {
    var id = [
        this.id, 
        (Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000000000))
    ].join('-');
    $(this).clone().attr('id', id);
});
```

Comment: One could also use the timestamp as a pseudorandom number:
    setAttribute('id', 'item_' + new Date().getTime() );

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.some_element').clone().attr('id','some_unique_id');
```

Comment: @KennethB: So, next time you clone it, give it a different ID.

Comment: @KennethB Please word your question properly then. You may have meant to say 'While cloning an element several times, how would you give each one a unique id?'